# flickity slider ref undefined

Tags: reactjs, flickity

So I have this react flickity slider component.

On first render the flickityRef returns undefined. If i change something in the file and the dev server updates the component. The flickityRef gets the correct ref.

My issue is that the onEngagement callback is not working before the component has done a re render.

**Update**

The above problem is now solved. Another issue is i render a component in the slider that has a filter.
[image]

Normally you can click a slider element and it will slide to that element on click. But it does not work on initial render for this component as flickityRef is undefined. If i then click the filter and the slider re-renders. Or i save in dev mode and det hot reload re-renders. It works and flickityRef is something. I have not hade any luck finding the issue as it works when rendering other components in the slider.

Here is the new code:

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useCallback } from "react";
import { isBrowser } from "@cryos/helpers/browser.helper";
import Flickity from "flickity";

export interface ICarouselProps {
  content: JSX.Element[] | undefined;
  previewNext?: boolean;
  startIndex?: number;
  fullscreen?: boolean;
  cellAlign?: "left" | "right" | "center";
  onCarouselChangeCallback?: (index: number) => void;
  getFlickityRef?: (ref: Flickity) => void;
  /**
   * Triggered when certain events happen for tracking purposes.
   */
  onEngagement?: () => void;
  dontChangeSlideOnClick?: boolean;
}

export const Carousel = React.memo<ICarouselProps>((props) => {
  const {
    content,
    previewNext,
    onCarouselChangeCallback,
    startIndex,
    fullscreen,
    onEngagement,
    dontChangeSlideOnClick,
    getFlickityRef,
  } = props;

  const FlickityComponent = isBrowser ? require("react-flickity-component") : "div";

  const flickityRef = useRef<Flickity>();

  let cellAlignment = previewNext ? "left" : "center";
  cellAlignment = props.cellAlign ? props.cellAlign : cellAlignment;

  const handleOnEngagement = useCallback(() => {
    onEngagement?.();
  }, [onEngagement]);

  const setFlickityRef = useCallback(
    (ref: Flickity) => {
      flickityRef.current?.off("change", handleOnEngagement);

      flickityRef.current = ref;
      if (getFlickityRef) {
        getFlickityRef(ref);
      }

      flickityRef.current?.on("change", handleOnEngagement);
    },
    [handleOnEngagement, getFlickityRef],
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    const flickity = flickityRef.current;

    const onChange = (index?: number) => {
      if (typeof index !== "undefined" && onCarouselChangeCallback) {
        onCarouselChangeCallback(index);
      }
    };

    const onStaticClick = (_event?: Event, _pointer?: Element | Touch, _cellElement?: Element, cellIndex?: number) => {
      if (typeof cellIndex !== "undefined" && !dontChangeSlideOnClick && flickity) {
        flickity.select(cellIndex);
      }
    };

    if (flickity) {
      flickity.on("change", onChange);
      flickity.on("staticClick", onStaticClick);
    }

    return () => {
      if (flickity) {
        flickity.off("change", onChange);
        flickity.off("staticClick", onStaticClick);
      }
    };
  }, [content, onCarouselChangeCallback, dontChangeSlideOnClick]);

  return (
    <>
      {content && content.length > 1 ? (
        <div
          className={`c-carousel ${previewNext ? "c-carousel--preview" : ""} ${
            fullscreen ? "c-carousel--fullscreen" : ""
          }`}
        >
          <FlickityComponent
            flickityRef={setFlickityRef}
            className="c-carousel__flickity"
            options={{
              dragThreshold: 10,
              imagesLoaded: true,
              arrowShape: "M 20,50 L 70,100 L 75,95 L 30,50  L 75,5 L 70,0 Z",
              cellAlign: cellAlignment,
              initialIndex: startIndex || 0,
              setGallerySize: true,
            }}
          >
            {content}
          </FlickityComponent>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <>{content && content[0]}</>
      )}
    </>
  );
});

Carousel.displayName = "Carousel";
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "the onEngagement callback is not working"? A code snippet demonstrating the issue would be helpful.

Comment: The onEngagement callback function should trigger every time someone engages with the slider. It basically just sendt some datalayer stuff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see if the following pattern addresses your use case. The idea is to subscribe to flickity events just one time inside the ref callback function.

```js
import * as React from "react";
import Flickity from "react-flickity-component";

import "flickity/css/flickity.css";

type CarouselProps = {
  onChange?: () => void;
};

export default function Carousel({ onChange }: CarouselProps) {
  const flickityRef = React.useRef<Flickity>();
  const onChangeRef = React.useRef(onChange);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    onChangeRef.current = onChange;
  });

  const handleOnChange = React.useCallback(() => {
    onChangeRef.current?.();
  }, []);

  const setFlickityRef = React.useCallback((ref: Flickity) => {
    flickityRef.current?.off("change", handleOnChange);
    
    flickityRef.current = ref;

    flickityRef.current?.on("change", handleOnChange);
  }, []);

  return (
    <Flickity flickityRef={setFlickityRef}>
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300" />
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/238/200/300" />
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/239/200/300" />
    </Flickity>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/stackoverflow-76558602-xz83nz?file=%2Fsrc%2FCarousel.tsx

Comment: The only issue is that it fires the event 2 times every time you engage with the slider.

Comment: Sure, it was a dev-only issue in strict mode. Please see the updated code above.

Comment: This seems to work, but is giving me another issue. Sometimes some of the slider items can be clicked and expand in height. Before the slider would expand with it so the navigations dots etc would move down. Now the item expand but you can not se half of it because the slider no longer adjusts :)

Comment: Got it to work. But I am having another issue. Will update the post.